# How to plot the running time as a function of its variables in R?

Tags: r, plot, runtime, norm

I have the following function in R:

```
compute.Euclidean.norm <- function(n) {  #vector of n-dimension  
  sum <- 0  
  for (i in seq_along(n)) { #for loop    
    sum <- sum + (n^2)    
    i <- i+1    
  }  
  return(sum)  
}
```

I want to plot the runtime of the three methods as n increases to a large enough value so that the runtime patterns become stable.

Comment: I am wondering how to plot it :(

Comment: What do you mean "three methods"?